# How to connect landline phone

Tags: pi-2

I am a newbie in this domain. I want to create landline phone using RPi, even after searching i couldn't find relevant stuff . Please help .

Functionalities :

1. Connect to existing telephone line , do basic call related activities.

Comment: How far have you got?  Could you detail all the sites you have looked at and which were the most helpful?

Comment: Where do you live? If you're in the US you should drop this project. Phone lines are heavily regulated, and even if you don't run into legal trouble with the government, the phone company will probably have words for you.

Comment: @Jacobm001 : i am living in India, as i know there is no regulations issue.

Comment: @joan : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=69555&p=506071 and

Comment: Please consider using the input that *you got* from the link you've posted to refine the question. Please do not expect people trying to answer here to follow that link and figure out what part of it fits you and which does not.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this may be more complex than you imagined, given the level of detail in your question.

To "connect to existing telephone line" you need a telephone line interface - not too hard to create with some basic electronics.  Read all about it [here](http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/teleinterface.html) for example.

To "do basic call related activites", I guess you mean dialling, going on/off hook, detecting ringing etc.  For dialling you will need a DTMF generator, which you can do in software on the Pi.  A quick Google search turned up [this](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~jhahn/python/DTMF.pyc) and there are many others.  Detecting ringing and going on/off hook are explained in the first link, about telephone line interfaces.

The Pi's audio output should plumb easily enough into a suitable telephone line interface.  The Pi does not have an audio *input* so you'll need to add one to connect to your telephone line interface, perhaps like [this](https://www.pi-supply.com/product/usb-audio-adapter-raspberry-pi/?gclid=Cj0KEQjwz-i3BRDtn53Z5Z7t4PUBEiQA23q2AMybw2kb3zCzoo2qdRKDRztJBM9hoTkyBGGM8lvyc6QaApJh8P8HAQ&v=79cba1185463).

As for "create a web interface via which I can make calls" - this is a huge topic and you don't give any indication of what you know.  You might consider using PHP to call external programs, for example.  There are many options here but perhaps that will give you an idea to start with.

Then you'll be able to make sounds on the line and receive sounds from the line.  You don't mention what you want to do with them.