# Connecting Pi to an old analog phone

Tags: communication

I want to connect an analog telephone set with Raspi which will house a telephone directory. Using telephone set's digits (alphabets) any user shall interact with GUI on Raspi to search for a number. Then picking up of the cradle to make the call through to the desired (searched) number. So basically Raspi to have a GUI with complete telephone directory and some interface with the telephone set.

I have this [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44911/how-to-connect-landline-phone) useful, but it is using pi as a telephone set and the idea of a GUI with a telephone directory is missing.

I am new to the world of pi.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Note: how to do this is far too broad. I would suggest taking the site's tour to get a feel for how to improve your question.

Comment: You'd have to modify the telephone quite a bit, does your telephone authority allow connecting modified equipment to the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the phone to a ATA box. The ATA box is a box that convert old plain telephony to VoIP (Voice Over IP) and then you can use a VoIP PBX (suggestion Asterisk) that can interact with the telephone in the way you wish.